# Weirdness with unsigned int, float data types and multiplication

Tags: c, unsigned, unsigned-integer

I am not very good at C language and just met a problem I don't understand. The code is:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 100;
    unsigned int b = 200;
    float c = 2;

    int result_i;
    unsigned int result_u;
    float result_f;

    result_i = (a - b)*2;
    result_u = (a - b);
    result_f = (a-b)*c;

    printf("%d\n", result_i);
    printf("%d\n", result_u);
    printf("%f\n", result_f);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
-200
-100
8589934592.000000
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

For (a-b) is negative and a,b are unsigned int type, (a-b) is trivial. And after multiplying a float type number c, the result is 8589934592.000000. I have two questions:

First, why the result is non-trivial after multiplying int type number 2 and assigned to an int type number?

Second, why the result_u is non-trivial even though (a-b) is negative and result_u is unsigned int type?

I am using Xcode to test this code, and the compiler is the default APPLE LLVM 6.0.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by "non-trivial?"

Comment: `printf("%d\n", result_u);`--> `printf("%u\n", result_u);`

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think "trivial" is equal to meaningless, "non-trivial" is the opposite.

Comment: Yes, it should be "%u" instead of %d. But I was wondering why "%d" can have the right result? Thanks.

Comment: Also you can modify result_f = ((float) a-b)* c; and you can keep printf("%f\n", result_f);

Comment: trivial doesn't mean meaningless and non-trivial is not the opposite of meaningless. 'non-trivial' generally means 'not simple or obvious'

Answer (score 6):

Your assumption that `a - b` is negative is completely incorrect.

Since `a` and `b` have `unsigned int` type all arithmetic operations with these two variables are performed in the domain of `unsigned int` type. The same applies to mixed "`unsigned int` with `int`" arithmetic as well. Such operations implement modulo arithmetic, with the modulo being equal to `UINT_MAX + 1`.

This means that expression `a - b` produces a result of type `unsigned int`. It is a large positive value equal to `UINT_MAX + 1 - 100`. On a typical platform with 32-bit `int` it is `4294967296 - 100 = 4294967196`.

Expression `(a - b) * 2` also produces a result of type `unsigned int`. It is also a large positive value (`UINT_MAX + 1 - 100` multiplied by `2` and taken modulo `UINT_MAX + 1`). On a typical platform it is `4294967096`.

This latter value is too large for type `int`. Which means that when you force it into a variable `result_i`, signed integer overflow occurs. The result of signed integer overflow on assignment is *implementation defined*. In your case `result_i` ended up being `-200`. It looks "correct", but this is not guaranteed by the language. (Albeit it might be guaranteed by your implementation.)

Variable `result_u` receives the correct unsigned result - a positive value `UINT_MAX + 1 - 100`. But you print that result using `%d` format specifier in `printf`, instead of the proper `%u`. It is illegal to print `unsigned int` values that do not fit into the range of `int` using `%d` specifier. The behavior of your code is *undefined* for that reason. The `-100` value you see in the output is just a manifestation of that undefined behavior. This output is formally meaningless, even though it appears "correct" at the first sight.

Finally, variable `result_f` receives the "proper" result of `(a-b)*c` expression, calculated without overflows, since the multiplication is performed in the `float` domain. What you see is that large positive value I mentioned above, multiplied by `2`. It is likely rounded to the precision of `float` type though, which is implementation-defined. The exact value would be `4294967196 * 2 = 8589934392`.

One can argue that the last value you printed is the only one that properly reflects the properties of unsigned arithmetic, i.e. it is "naturally" derived from the actual result of `a - b`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In the expression (a - b) * 2, is 2 also automatically regarded as unsigned int? Is it because a,b are unsigned int?

Comment: @facebook-1536745818; Yes.

Comment: @facebook-1536745818: Formally, `2` is an `int`. But when you mix signed and unsigned types of the same size, the unsigned type "wins" and the evaluation is performed in the domain of unsigned type. So, yes, `2` gets interpreted as unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

You get negative numbers in the printf because you've asked it to print a signed integer with %d. Use %u if you want to see the actual value you ended up with. That will also show you how you ended up with the output for the float multiplication.

Comment: How will it show how he ended up with the float output? He prints a float using `%f` which is already correct.

Comment: It will show the correct value of the the unsigned int result, which makes the output of the %f printf obvious.